# How to solve Postgres and folder Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750) running docker on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-11

I've been trying to run a postgres container on Docker with command

```
docker compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```

but it shows me the following message:

```
2024-02-02 14:33:26.362 UTC [52] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid permissions
2024-02-02 14:33:26.362 UTC [52] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
```

I'm currently using Windows 11.

How can I fix this permission issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL7zB.png)

I tried to point to another folder, like "data2" but it doesn't work correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way that worked for me, imagine you have only this `db` service and you have specified your volumes like this, add a `volumes:` in the end of you docker compose file and add mounted folder path in your host, then docker will manage the permissions for you:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: `volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Is this postgres_data a folder that will be created on my project?

Comment: no, `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is the folder that postgres saves the data in your container, when you use this command this folder will be mapped to `postgres_data` folder in your local project. So if you shut down the container and run again, data will be retrieved automatically.
But to solve the error you encountered you should just add `volumes:
  postgres_data:` in the end of you docker compose file.